# Is it recommended to const_cast this for deletion in the Release function when implementing reference counting?

Tags: c++

I was implementing reference counting in one of my programs. Because I intended that portions of code holding `const` pointers of the reference-counted object may duplicate the pointer, I declared the `AddRef` and `Release` member functions as `const`, and the reference counting variable as `mutable`. Now the problem is that, the `Release` member function would need to delete the object if the reference count reaches `0`, while a non-`const` pointer to the object is required if the object is to be deleted. Defining a reference counted object as `const` obviously makes no sense, so there's no practical situation where it will get a non-`const` pointer to an object originally defined as `const`. Is it considered recommended if I use `const_cast` on `this` in this case?

I searched on the Internet about usage of `const_cast`. Some say that it should only be used when passing parameters to some `const`-incorrect API that you know for sure won't actually modify the object. This is not in my case.

```
class ReferenceCountedObject : public virtual IReferenceCountedObject {
public:
    inline virtual ~ReferenceCountedObject() = default;
    inline virtual uintptr_t AddRef() const {
        if (this) {
            uintptr_t ret = ++this->ref_count;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    inline virtual uintptr_t Release() const {
        if (this) {
            uintptr_t ret = --this->ref_count;
            if (!ret) const_cast<ReferenceCountedObject*>(this)->DeleteMe();
            return ret;
        }
    }
protected:
    inline virtual void DeleteMe() = 0;
private:
    mutable std::atomic<uintptr_t> ref_count = 1;
};
```

Comment: CRTP seems more adapted than runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Doesn't `std::shared_ptr` fulfill your requirements ?

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::shared_ptr` fulfills my requirements. However, I declare `IReferenceCountedObject` in a header file that's supposed to be used across executable module boundaries. As different compilers or different versions of compilers may have incompatible implementations of STL classes, I could not use `std::shared_ptr` in this case. The `ReferenceCountedObject` class itself however, is not used across executable module boundaries, so using `std::atomic` inside would not be problematic.

Comment: @BowenYang "*I intended that portions of code holding `const` pointers of the reference-counted object may duplicate the pointer*" - that sounds highly suspicious, especially if it forces you to break your class design. Reference counting is not a const operation and so `AddRef` and `Release` should definitely NOT be declared as `const`. Can you provide a [mcve] that is causing you trouble?

Comment: What’s this all about?  You **can** [`delete` a pointer to `const`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#2).